# Popup message like Dialog

Tags: android, android-layout, android-dialog

I'm actually coding an app for Android and I need some help to do something.
I need to do a kind of popup message with this image: http://img716.imageshack.us/img716/9331/postitz.png. This image must have 2 TextView, one of them is a title and the other one is the message.

I have tried some options like Dialog with its own layout, own style, but the image fills all the screen instead of wrap the content of the TextViews. I have also tried to do it with a new Activity and occurs the same, the Image fills all the screen.

My actual layout is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:background="@android:color/white">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/img_postit"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/postit"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/note_titulo"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:padding="30dp"/>

        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/note_descr"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:padding="30dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

But I have tried with a lot of different combinations, RelativeLayout, FrameLayout, and I cannot find the solution to do this.

Any idea of how to resolve it?.

Thank's for all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you said you used as a new activity. Did you use  `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog` in your manifest file?

And be sure that the image is little bit smaller one such that it will be suitable to act as a pop up..
If you used a dialog what exactly is the problem? Didnt you get the dialog as a pop up ?
(i think the image is larger so that it might fill the entire screen)

Comment: I have tried with a smaller image and it works, thanks, I always have problems with images and resolutions in Android!! jajaja. Thanks for all !

Answer (score 1):

Create your own class extending dialog.And use layout like following. I use this in one of my apps and the dialog window is wrapped around the buttons :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/background"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ll1"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/start"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/stop"
        android:background="@drawable/start_on"
        android:button="@android:color/transparent"
        android:checked="true" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/stop"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/stop_off"
        android:button="@android:color/transparent" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/restart"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/stop"
        android:background="@drawable/restart_on"
        android:button="@android:color/transparent" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/lltext"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/detail_credit"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ll2"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/startText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/stopText"
        android:text="@string/start_server_icon"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/stopText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
        android:text="@string/stop_server_icon"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/restartText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/stopText"
        android:text="@string/restart_server_icon"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</RelativeLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/dialogButtonOK"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/lltext"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="OK" />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: It works with an image more tiny, the problem was that the image i was using was too bigger and it fill the screen, but i have updated my layout with RelativeLayout and it works better, thanks for answer :)

Answer (score 0):

```
final Dialog dialog_my = new Dialog(FIRST.this,
                    android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);
            dialog_my.setContentView(R.layout.about_us); //<PUT YOUR LAYOUT ID HERE>
            TextView date = (TextView) dialog_my.findViewById(R.id.date);

            TextView thought = (TextView) dialog_my.findViewById(R.id.thought);

            TextView ok = (TextView) dialog_my.findViewById(R.id.ok);
            TextView link = (TextView) dialog_my.findViewById(R.id.link);
            TextView contact = (TextView) dialog_my.findViewById(R.id.contact);
            WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = dialog_my.getWindow().getAttributes();
            lp.dimAmount = 0.0f;
            dialog_my.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
            dialog_my.getWindow().addFlags(
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);
            dialog_my.show();
```